# Работа с mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-modules, mod_rewrite

Обработка `http://test.ru/photo/111.html`

Есть правило `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php?part=$1&id=$2`.

В скрипт передаются 2 переменные: `part` и `id`.

Вопрос? Как сделать правило, чтобы срабатывало при `http://test.ru/photo/` и при `http://test.ru/photo/111.html`, т.е если 2-й переменной нет, то и фиг с ней.

Т.е. вторая переменная может быть, а может и не быть...

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?part=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php?part=$1&id=$2
```